# Is it true that $F^*\wr S_n$ is a solvable group, when $n\leq 5$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, solvable-groups, linear-groups, wreath-product

Let $U$  be a linear space over a  division ring $D$, $G_1$ a subgroup  of
$GL(U)$, and $\Gamma$ a subgroup of a symmetric group $S_k$ on $\{1,\ldots,k\}, k>1$.
The cartesian product $U^k=V_1$ can be regarded as a linear space over $D$, and we write
any vector $v\in V_1$ in the form $v=(u_1,\ldots,u_k)$, $u_j\in U$. For any $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in G_1$ and
$s\in \Gamma$, we define a mapping $f:V_1\rightarrow V_1$, $f=\langle f_1,\ldots,f_k,s\rangle$, by setting
$$f(v)=f(u_1,\ldots,u_k)=\overline{v} \in V_1,$$
where the $s(v)$th component of  $\overline{v}$ is $f_v(u_v)$, $v=1,\ldots,k.$ Obviously $f$ is
an automorphism of $V_1$. The group of all such automorphisms  is called the wreath product of the skew linear group
$G_1$ and the permutation group $\Gamma$, and is denoted by $G_1\wr \Gamma$.

Recall that a monomial matrix is a square matrix with exactly one non-zero entry in each row and column. Assume that $F$ is a field.
It is not hard to see that the set of all $n\times n$ monomial matrices over $F$ is conjugate to
$F^*\wr S_n$, when $n>1$, when $S_n$ is the symmetric group over $n$ elements.
We know that for $n>5$, $S_n$ is not solvable. Since $F^*\wr S_n$ has a copy of $S_n$, therefore for  $n>5$, $F^*\wr S_n$ is not solvable.
Is it true that $F^*\wr S_n$  is a solvable group, when $n\leq 5$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $\wr$ stands for a wreath product, note that any wreath product $A\wr_{\Omega}B$ has a quotient isomorphic to $B$.

Comment: $S_5$ is not solvable so the answer to your question is no.

Comment: yes. it is correct.